# How to change wget default directory from 'Videos' to 'Downolads'?

Tags: downloads, wget

I use the combination of **Flashgot** and **wget** for downloads. I reset my Firefox preferences due to some other problems. Then I reconfigured everything (including add-ons, cache, etc).

After that, when I tried to download something, it automatically saved into the "Videos" folder. But before resetting the settings, I could download items to "Downloads".

What should I do to make the default directory of wget to "Downloads"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I was aware wget usually downloads into the current working directory. You have the following options to specify the directory.

1.Change to the directory you wish it to be downloaded to first then run your wget command.

```
cd /home/yourname/Downloads
```

Then run your wget command

```
wget http://download.files.com/software/files.tar.gz
```

2.Add the directory to the wget command like this.

```
wget -P /home/yourname/Downloads http://download.files.com/software/files.tar.gz
```

Comment: when i clicks on the flashgot icon, there is no need of executing commands manually. It shows commands automatically in an X-Terminal. There is no space to type a comand. It does everything automatically. And i need to change the default folder.

Comment: Your question asks about the "wget default directory" and you go on to say "I use the combination of Flashgot and wget for downloads". You might want to clarify that you are looking for the default download directory of Flashgot. This should help http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4811

Comment: the last command gave me `/home/ohad/Downloads: Is a directory` error.
-O tells wget to download into a file.

Comment: The flag should be `-P /target_dir`

Answer (score 29):

#### **wget** by default will store downloads to the current directory where you run the wget command.

**Method 1: Pass the `-P` option to specify a download directory**

- To change the directory, you need to add the `-P` argument in your wget command:

  ```
  wget -P /path/to/directory <download-url>
  ```

  Or

  ```
  wget --directory-prefix=prefix <download-url>
  ```

  where **prefix** is the directory where you want the downloads to be stored.

  With this method, you need to specify the `-P` or `--directory-prefix=prefix` every time you download.

**Method 2: Use alias to make a permanent default directory**

- To set a permanent default download directory, you can use `alias`, like this:

  ```
  alias wget='wget --directory-prefix=prefix'
  ```

  Change `prefix` with the directory you want and put the alias command on `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: when i clicks on the flashgot icon, there is no need of executing commands manually. It shows commands automatically in an X-Terminal. There is no space to type a comand. It does everything automatically. And i need to change the default folder.

Comment: I see. Try the second method, since Flashgot will use the system's wget settings.